# Как задать межбуквенный интервал в TextView?

Tags: android, android-textview

У меня есть дизайн, в нем используются шрифты. У меня есть эти шрифты, но проблема в том, что шрифты имеют межбуквенный интервал. Я нашел некоторые статьи в которых советуют переопределить `TextView`, сделал это, теперь я могу задавать этот интервал в  dpi. Но он работает безумно криво, например, платный скрипт фотошопа мне показал:

```
FONT 
Block Berthold Regular (bold)
19.2 px
#FFFFFF / rgb(255,255,255)
Letter spacing: +2.69 px
Line height: 36.48 px
```

картинка в расширении 1440 на 2560 пикселей. это xxxhdpi. чтобы все выглядело идентично мне пришлось задать интервал `-0.73dp`  я не понимаю как решить эту задачу.

вот мой `TextView`:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    private float letterSpacing = 0.0f;
    private CharSequence originalText = "";
    private Typeface typeface;

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        isInEditMode();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        isInEditMode();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray attributesArray = getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
        letterSpacing = attributesArray.getDimension(R.styleable.MyTextView_letterSpacing, 0.0f);
        String fontName = attributesArray.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_fontName);
        if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
            if (null == fontName) {
                typeface = Fonts.getBlockBertholdRegular(context);
            } else {
                typeface = Fonts.get(context, fontName);
            }
            super.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
        originalText = super.getText();
        applyLetterSpacing();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getLetterSpacing() {
        return letterSpacing;
    }

    public void setLetterSpacing(float letterSpacing) {
        this.letterSpacing = letterSpacing;
        applyLetterSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        originalText = text;
        applyLetterSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getText() {
        return originalText;
    }

    private void applyLetterSpacing() {
        if (this == null || this.originalText == null) return;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < originalText.length(); i++) {
            String c = "" + originalText.charAt(i);
            builder.append(c.toUpperCase());
            if (i + 1 < originalText.length()) {
                builder.append("\u00A0");
            }
        }
        SpannableString finalText = new SpannableString(builder.toString());
        if (builder.toString().length() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < builder.toString().length(); i += 2) {
                finalText.setSpan(new ScaleXSpan((letterSpacing + 1) / 10), i, i + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }

        super.setText(finalText, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
            super.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Может пока не стоит ничего переопределять.

Как насчет этого [android:textScaleX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textScaleX) свойства и метода setTextScaleX(float) для обычного TextView?

Comment: можно пример? как мне используя это установить точно такой же интервал как показывает фотошоп?

Comment: android:textScaleX  просто растягивает TextView. мне нужно увеличивать только интервал между буквами

Comment: Такая возможность появилась в android 5.0,  метод `setLetterSpacing()`.  До него, думаю, самым надежным вариантом будет изменить межбуквенный интервал редактором шрифтов

Comment: @lsillarionov не совсем понял. я могу менять интервал в кастомной вьюшке. но подогнав для рдного екрана и запустив на другом все криво. как я могу сделать одинаково для всех екранов используя редактор шрифтов?

Comment: и да setLetterSpacing() я тоже использовал на Lolipop - так же работает не верно