# Как изменить межбуквенное растояние?

Tags: android, android-textview

Как убрать/уменьшить межбуквенный интервал (запас для символа другой ширины)?

C [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413083/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B2-textview) ознакомился, но ни вариант с кастомной вьюхой, ни `android:textScaleX` мне не подходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эту возможность добавили в API 21: `.setLetterSpacing(float)` 
или в xml файл: `android:letterSpacing`
Если вы хотите решить эту задачу в более ранних версиях, вам нужно создать ваш TextView

```
 public myTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

в AttributeSet написать пару строчек, в которых проставите свои "spacing" между буквами.

Comment: а каким образом непосредственно в коде кастомной вьюхи проставлять эти отступы?

Comment: вот пример, сразу нашел: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23216171/5490632

Comment: вы скинули ссылку на вариант который описан по той ссылке что я давал в начале вопроса. Но у меня этот вариант почему то не срабатывал и при установке setLetterSpacing() говорит что  работает с  API 21. Какое значение нужно установить .setLetterSpacing(); что бы уменьшить отступ, потому что все что у меня получилось - так это увеличить отступ?

Comment: Все, понял, нужно было значение отрицательное устанавливать